# How to use cells of datagridview columns as array elements in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview table on my windows forms with 5 columns;

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkGiT.png)

gX, gY, gZ, pX, pY. When a user enters values in the table, I want to make each column into an array whose number of elements is the number of row values entered by the user. This is the code I wrote, but is not working:

```
    Dim t As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    Dim groundX(t) As Double
    Dim groundY(t) As Double
    Dim groundZ(t) As Double
    Dim photoX(t) As Double
    Dim photoY(t) As Double


    For i As Integer = 0 To t
        groundX(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("gX").Value)
        groundY(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("gY").Value)
        groundZ(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("gZ").Value)
        photoX(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("pX").Value)
        photoY(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("pY").Value)
    Next
```

Comment: Saying "it's not working" is NEVER an adequate description of a problem.  ALWAYS describe EXACTLY what does happen and how that differs from your expectation.

Comment: I receive NullException error

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. So which reference on the line that throws the exception is null, i.e. `Nothing`?  My money is on the fact that you haven't actually named your columns and thus you cannot get a cell by column name.  You should try using an index instead.

Comment: Can't guarantee that all the columns have been filled add a little validation in there.  if  DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("gX") IsNot Nothing Then groundX(i) = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("gX").Value)